# How to I make the device go to sleep in code?

Tags: android

I Searched the web on how can I force the device to turn the screen off (emulating the power press key was an option) but found little to no info.

I`m trying to build a lock screen app so I want on a click of a button to turn the kiosk mode on (so just my lock screen can run, and once authenticated it will close itself) and after the kiosk mode is turned on I want to make the device sleep.

is there any way I can do so?

By now I have my lock screen app, and a prototype of the kiosk mode I want to add the turn off screen option in this part of the code right in the onCreate Method:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    findViewById(R.id.next).setOnClickListener(this);
    setUpKioskMode();

}


    private void setUpKioskMode() {
    if (!MySharedPreferences.isAppLaunched(this)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate() locking the app first time");
        kioskMode.lockUnlock(this, true);
        MySharedPreferences.saveAppLaunched(this, true);
    } else {
        //check if app was locked
        if (MySharedPreferences.isAppInKioskMode(this)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate() locking the app");
            kioskMode.lockUnlock(this, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you have done so far?

Comment: please go through it once https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin . if you want to use lock from your application you'll need to register your app as device administrator.

Comment: @PratikButani I Edited my post. thanks

Comment: @Urvishrana Wow it is as easy as "private lateinit var dpm: DevicePolicyManager
dpm.lockNow()" after getting this permission?  thanks I will try that

Comment: @YairLandmann yes once you register your app as device administrator you can do it as simple as that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To lock the screen of the device you'll need to explore the Device Administration API, letting their users lock the device screen directly inside an application.

You can follow the following steps to achieve this.

1. Create a policies.xml inside `res/xml/policies.xml`

**policies.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-policies>
        <force-lock />
    </uses-policies>
</device-admin>
```

2. Add this in `Manifest.xml` inside `application` tag.

   ```
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED"/>
       </intent-filter>

   </receiver>
   ```
3. Create a `MyAdmin` class a subclass of the DeviceAdminReceiver class.

   ```
   public class MyAdmin extends DeviceAdminReceiver {

   @Override
   public void onEnabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
       Toast.makeText(context, "Device Admin : enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }

   @Override
   public void onDisabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
       Toast.makeText(context, "Device Admin : disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }    }
   ```
4. In your Activity:

> ```
> private DevicePolicyManager devicePolicyManager;
>
>  private ComponentName compName;
>
> //initialize in onCreate 
>   devicePolicyManager=(DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
>            compName=new ComponentName(this,MyAdmin.class);
>        //initialize in Oncreate 
>         devicePolicyManager=DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
>        compName=new ComponentName(this,MyAdmin.class);
>
> @onClick Button
> boolean active=devicePolicyManager.isAdminActive(compName);
>
>         if(active){
>         devicePolicyManager.lockNow();
>         }else{
>         Toast.makeText(this,"You need to enable the Admin Device Features",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>         }
> ```

5. To ask for user permission:

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);      intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, compName);      intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION, "Additional text explaining why we need this permission");startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_ENABLE);
   ```

and Check for its result

```
   @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch(requestCode) {
      case RESULT_ENABLE :
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You have enabled the Admin Device features", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Problem to enable the Admin Device features", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
      break;
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  }
}
```

[Here](https://medium.com/@ssaurel/creating-a-lock-screen-device-app-for-android-4ec6576b92e0) is the complete implementation of the same.

Comment: Thanks, Worked with this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JJcbB4FwtLY that uses this code and finally it worked